# NSwag vs Swashbuckle

Tags: .net, swagger, swashbuckle, nswag

I've read in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-5.0) that "The two main OpenAPI implementations for .NET are Swashbuckle and NSwag" but what are the differences between them?

Comment: I started using NSwag a while ago when Swashbuckle did not support OpenApi v3 standard yet. I think it supports that now.

Answer (score 28):

I would like to share information that I have found so far. It doesn't answer my question but might be useful for others. I found [a comment from RicoSuter](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/277#issuecomment-245305859) who develops NSwag:

> NSwag not only provides the functionality of Swashbuckle (Swagger
> generation) but also code generators. This way we can avoid
> incompatibilities and offer more features and a more streamlined
> toolchain.

But I don't accept this as the answer to my question because it doesn't have enough information to make a conscious decision about which tool to use.

I also found [a great blog post](https://alex-klaus.com/marry-csharp-typescript/) that compares tools to generate typescript clients from swagger schema. But it doesn't have information about Swashbuckle because Swashbuckle doesn't generate client code.

Comment: Note that Swashbuclk.AspNetCore is being removed in .NET 9. See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54599